# Why is this Square Root approximation not working?

Tags: c#

This Program basically finds an approximation to the square root of a given number. I can't see the problem why its not working. The program is compiling but never running. It'd computing something indefinitely.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number to find Square Root");
        var num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        var ans = SqaureRoot(num);
        Console.WriteLine("Square root of {0} : {1}",num,ans);

    }
```

The problem must obviously be in this method, in my opinion, the code is not exiting from the while true loop, and i just can't see why. This problem has to be tackled using the Newton Raphson method only to approximate the square root. Could it be maybe since the newton raphson equation doesn't have brackets?

```
    public static double SqaureRoot(double a)
    {
        if (a < 0)
            throw new Exception("Can not sqrt a negative number");
        double error = 0.00001;
        double x = 1;
        while (true)
        {
            double val = x * x;
            if (Math.Abs(a) <= error)
                return x;
            x = x / 2 + a / (2 * x);
        }

    }
```

Comment: the variable a is never reassigne. So the exit condition will never be true.

Comment: Today would be a great day to learn how to use a debugger. Stepping through the code in the debugger would find your problem almost immediately, and then you would be able to find your problems yourself rather than polling strangers on the internet. If you want more good advice on how to debug small programs, see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Misspell: `SqaureRoot`

Comment: Another technique you could use that would solve this problem is to explain, out loud, in words, to yourself or a friend why it is that every line is correct. When you get to the line that is obviously incorrect you will be unable to clearly explain why it is correct because it is not.

Comment: Another technique you can use in this case is to ask "what is the purpose of every variable?" and "is it used for that purpose?"  You have a variable that's has a purpose but is not being used for that purpose, and that's the bug.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> I can't see the problem why its not working. ... the code is not exiting from the while true loop, and i just can't see why.

It's true, you can't see it. All the time I'm looking in the refrigerator *at the milk* and I can't see the milk.  You have Refrigerator Blindness but for coding. You are looking directly at an obvious defect and you cannot see it.

**This problem is very, very common amongst both beginners and experienced programmers.**

It's also very common amongst humans. You have a bias towards reading what you think is there, even when it is not:

```
           /\
          /I \
         /LOVE\
        /PARIS \
       / IN THE \
      /THE SPRING\
     --------------
```

The first time they read it, most people read "*I love Paris in the spring*", but *that's not what it says*.

The program you are analyzing in your head is the one that works, but that program only exists in your head. You have to analyze the program that you actually wrote and is actually running!  This is essentially a form of *confirmation bias* -- the tendency to observe evidence that supports your wrong belief that the code is correct, and fail to see evidence that contradicts it.

There are many techniques that experienced developers use every day to break out of code blindness and find the defect.

The technique you're using is *ask people with fresh eyes to look at the problem*. This technique works; I just had to glance at your code to see the obvious problem because *I'm reading the code that you wrote*, and you're reading *the code that doesn't exist that you thought you wrote*.

But that's a bad technique because it wastes other people's time on trivial problems that you could learn to solve yourself. **Today would be a great day to learn how to solve those problems yourself.**

The first technique is to *learn how to use a debugger*.

What you want to do is step through the code in the debugger, one statement at a time, and on every statement make a prediction about what that statement will do. **You have to make the prediction before you step the statement**.  Then step the statement and see if your prediction came true. Eventually you'll make a prediction that is false, and that's the point where your understanding of your program is wrong.

This works for our optical illusion as well. If you tell people to read a word, pause, and read the next word, it becomes easy to see the error.

The next technique is called *rubber duck debugging*.

Get a rubber duck or a grad student or some other object you can talk to, and **out loud** explain every line of your program -- preferably while debugging -- and give an *excessively detailed* explanation of why that line is correct.  When you get to a line you cannot justify, either you don't understand your own program, or the line is wrong.

You will feel like an idiot talking out loud to a rubber duck, but part of what makes it work is engaging the part of your brain responsible for speaking.  And again, this works for our illusion: if you read every word and say the sentence out loud, instead of reading the whole sentence and then saying the whole sentence, the error becomes obvious.

In particular, *explain the purpose and usage of every variable very carefully*. In your case that alone would quickly find the problem, as you have a variable which is declared and written but never read. A variable which is written but never read from is a **huge** red flag; it means that you've either got a useless part in your machine, or, more likely, you've got a crucial part that is not being used by mistake.  As is the case here.

In your particular case there are some special techniques.

- Your intuition gave you two big hints: the problem is an infinite loop, and "Could it be maybe since the newton raphson equation doesn't have brackets?" The first intuition was spot on. The second intuition makes zero sense to me and I have no idea what you're talking about. But regardless, run down those hunches.
- You have correctly diagnosed your problem as an infinite loop, so focus your attention while debugging particularly on the loop condition.  Does it make sense?  (Hint: No.)  Again, read it out loud.  It helps.
- You are writing a code version of a standard algorithm. Go back to your description of the algorithm, and verify that **every step** in the algorithm is found somewhere in your code. There's an operation in the original algorithm that is not in your program, and that's where the bug is.
- Rename your variables so that their names more clearly represent their concepts. `error` is wrong; that's not the error. That's the `errorTolerance`.  `x` should be `approximation`. The error is computed by `currentError = approximation * approximation - a;` If you look at your program and ask yourself "where is `errorTolerance` compared to `currentError`? you'd easily find your bug.  And if you do that, **you'll write fewer silly bugs**.
- Generalize.  It is hard to see your error because you're not reading the code, you're reading its intended meaning.  You look at the code and what you see is:

---

```
SOLVER
{
    VALIDATE ARGUMENT
    INITIALIZE APPROXIMATION
    while (true)
    {
      if (WITHIN TOLERANCES)
        RETURN APPROXIMATION
      REFINE APPROXIMATION
    }
}
```

---

And **that code is right**.  You look at `if(Abs...` and see "I'm checking to see if I'm within tolerances", and that's the right place to do this step, and you don't even think "but did I correctly implement it?"

But since that's the structure you expect your code to take, **you could actually write it that way**:

```
class Solver
{
  private double a;
  private double approximation;

  private Solver(double a) {
    this.a = a;
  }

  public static double Solve(double a)
  {
    Solver s = new Solver(a);
    s.Validate();
    s.Initialize();
    while (true) {
      if (s.WithinTolerances())
        return s.approximation;
      s.Refine();
    }
  }

  private void Validate() { ... }
  private void Initialize() { ... }
  private bool WithinTolerances() { ... }
  private void Refine() { ... }
}
```

You are **way less likely to make an error** when you have a method that does *one thing* and does it *extremely well*, and bonus points if that method can be tested independently.

Notice that the class I just made above could be an abstract base class!  We could have a whole family of solvers that solved different problems using different techniques.

- Your code is sloppy in general.  `SqaureRoot` instead of `SquareRoot`.  `Exception` instead of `ArgumentException`.  And so on. Stop being sloppy. **Get in the habit of making every single line of code you ever write a model of clarity and precision.** It will make finding your inevitable mistakes much easier because you will not have to wade through a sea of smaller mistakes, some of which might be obscuring the larger mistake.

Any of these techniques would find your bug quickly. **Learn all of them today**.

Further reading:

- https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1316179/

Comment: "_The program you are analyzing in your head is the one that works, but that program only exists in your head._" It happens to me every time, not just with computer programming, but also with pen and paper. Sometimes I write "001" when I want "100" and I just see a "100" there no matter what. I've lost many points in exams because of this.

Comment: Great writeup as always Eric! You've put something into words that I've had in my head for a long time.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (Math.Abs(a) <= error)
    return x;
```

`a` isn't changing inside the loop, so it will never return.

As mentioned in the comment, you should compare to the error term `Math.Abs(a-val)`, instead of `Math.Abs(a)`, the initial value.

Comment: `a` shouldn't be changing. The problem is that the expression is wrong; it should be `Abs(a-val)` which does change.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have pointed, you never meet the condition to `return`.
Consider changing this:

```
if (Math.Abs(a) <= error)
```

into

```
if (Math.Abs(a - val) <= error)
```