# Storing numbers between two numbers in an array

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

as you can read from the title I'm trying to store all the numbers between two numbers in an array.
For example store the numbers between 21 and 43 (22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29...) in an array.

> This is the code, I don't know why but it prints only the higher number minus one.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int higher = 43;
        int lower = 21;
        int[] numbers = new int[22]; //the numbers between 21 and 43 are 22

        for (int i = lower; i < higher;i++)
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < 22; a++)
            {
                numbers[a] = i;
            }
        }
        for (int c = 0; c < 22; c++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(numbers[c]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite get the point of _two_ loops, but note that you could achieve the same with a simple `var numbers = Enumerable.Range(lower, higher - lower).ToArray();`

Comment: Well, reason it out. You have three loops.  What does the innermost loop of the three do? That is, if you had to explain its action *overall* in a sentence, what would you say?

Comment: @TetyanaKorogoda: Though that is correct, there is no point in telling absolute beginners about advanced techniques. This programmer does not understand for loops or how to debug simple problems. Help them crawl before you help them run!

Comment: Also, read my answer here carefully. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50351453/why-is-this-square-root-approximation-not-working/50351991#50351991  It has suggestions for how to solve problems where you can't see bugs you wrote yourself.

Comment: @Eric, I agree, but the solutions with LINQ one-liners here at SO really changed my understanding when I was a beginner :)

Comment: @Eric Lippert Ok thanks, I'll keep that in mind next time I have a bug that I cant' solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For everytime you loop through i, you put that number in every slot of the array. The inner loop is what is causing your issue. A better solution would be:

```
int higher = 43;
int lower = 21;
int[] numbers = new int[21]; 

int index = 0;
for (int i = lower + 1; i < higher; i++) // if you want to store everything 
                                         // between 21 and 43, you need to 
                                         // start with 22, thus lower + 1
{
    numbers[index] = i;
    index++;
}
for (int c = 0; c < 21; c++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(numbers[c]);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 11):

> This is the code, I don't know why but it prints only the higher number minus one.

This question will attract answers giving you a half dozen solutions you can cut and paste to do your assignment.

I note you did not ask a question in your question -- next time, please format your question in the form of a question.  The right question to ask here is **how do I learn how to spot mistakes in code I've written?** because that is the vital skill you lack. Answers that give you the code will not answer that question.

I already gave you a link to a recent answer where I explain that in detail, so study that.

In particular, in your case you have to read the program you wrote as though you had not written it.  As though you were coming fresh to the program that someone else wrote and trying to figure out what it does.

The first thing I would do is look at the inner loop and say to myself "what does this do, in words?"

```
        for (int a = 0; a < 22; a++)
        {
            numbers[a] = i;
        }
```

That is "put the value `i` in every slot of the array.  Now look at the outer loop:

```
    for (int i = lower; i < higher;i++)
    {
        put the value i in every slot of the array
    }
```

Now the technique to use here is to logically "unroll" the loop. A loop just does something multiple times so write that out. It starts with lower, it goes to higher-1, so that loop does this:

```
        put the value lower in every slot of the array
        put the value lower+1 in every slot of the array
        …
        put the value higher-1 in every slot of the array
```

What does the third loop do?

```
        print every item in the array
```

And now you know why it prints the highest number minus one multiple times.  Because *that's what the program does*. We just reasoned it out.

---

Incidentally the answers posted so far are correct, but some are not the best.

You have a technique that you understand for "do something to every member of an array, and that is:

```
loop an indexer from 0 to the array size minus one
    do something to the array slot at the indexer
```

But the solutions the other answers are proposing are the opposite:

```
loop an indexer from the lower to the higher value
    compute an index
    do something to the array slot at that index
```

It's important to understand that both are correct, but my feeling is that for the beginner you should stick with the pattern you know.  How would we

```
loop an indexer from 0 to the array size minus one
    do something to the array slot at the indexer
```

for your problem?  Let's start with giving you a much better technique for looping the indexer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; ++i)
```

That's a better technique because when you change the size of the array, you don't have to change the loop!  And also you are guaranteed that every slot in the array is covered.  **Design your loops so that they are robust to changes and have good invariants**.

Now you have to work out what the right loop body is:

```
{
    int number = i + lower;
    numbers[i] = number;
}
```

Now you know that your loop invariant is "when the loop is done, the array is full of consecutive numbers starting at lower".

Answer (score 0):

Replace a with a direct translation of i

```
for (int i = lower; i < higher;i++)
{
  numbers[i-lower] = i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
        int higher = 43;
        int lower = 21;
        int[] numbers = new int[22]; //the numbers between 21 and 43 are 22

        for (int i = lower+1; i < higher; i++)
        {

                numbers[i-lower] = i;



        }
        for (int c = 1; c < 21; c++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(numbers[c]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think higher & lower are variables so following will give you output
>   for any higher and lower numbers

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int higher = 43;
        int lower = 21;
        int numDiff = higher - lower - 1;
        int[] numbers = new int[numDiff]; //the numbers between 21 and 43 are 22
        for(int i = 0; i<numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = numDiff + i + 1;
        }
        for(int b = 0; b<numbers.Length; b++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(numbers[b]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```